# How to make sum of divergent series to use any regularization that succeeds?

Tags: bugs, summation

For instance,

```
Sum[x, {x, 1, Infinity}, Regularization -> Dirichlet]
Sum[Exp[x], {x, 1, Infinity}, Regularization -> Borel]
```

works, but

```
Sum[x, {x, 1, Infinity}, Regularization -> Borel]
Sum[Exp[x], {x, 1, Infinity}, Regularization -> Dirichlet]
```

Does not. How to make it automatically use the method that works?

Comment: You can specify, `VerifyConvergence -> False` to let it automatically select the `Regularization`. This seems to work well for the second case. I don't know why it doesn't for the first case. It looks like a bug because executing the first case returns convergence error, even when the convergence check is chosen to be `False`.

Comment: @Anjan Kumar I have added the bug tag

Comment: @AnjanKumar I think in the second case, it is simply applying the geometric series formula, without checking convergence. I don't think it is using any regularization, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Anixx @Michael E2 You may be right. In 11.1.0, they have added the same summation under `VerifyConvergence` showing the convergence error for  `VerifyConvergence -> False`. I think the heading seems to be misleading: it says `by default it checks for convergence`, whereas the example shown uses `VerifyConvergence -> False`.

Comment: I can't find a built-in way, so Iguess you could just iterate through `{"Abel", "Cesaro", "Euler", "Borel", "Dirichlet"}` until success. One could write a function to do this, if you're going to do it a lot.

Answer (score -2):

Following  [Mathematica help](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html), one may execute

```
Table[Sum[x, {x, 1, Infinity}, Regularization -> r], {r, {None, "Cesaro", "Abel", "Euler", "Borel",    "Dirichlet"}}]
```

> Sum::div: Sum does not converge.
>    Sum::div: Sum does not converge.
>   {Sum[x, {x, 1, [Infinity]}, Regularization -> None], 
>    Sum[x, {x, 1, [Infinity]}, Regularization -> "Cesaro"], 
>    Sum[x, {x, 1, [Infinity]}, Regularization -> "Abel"], 
>    Sum[x, {x, 1, [Infinity]}, Regularization -> "Euler"], 
>    Sum[x, {x, 1, [Infinity]}, Regularization -> "Borel"], -(1/12)}

and

```
Table[Sum[Exp[x], {x, 1, Infinity},Regularization -> r], {r, {None, "Cesaro", "Abel", "Euler", "Borel","Dirichlet"}}]
```

> Sum::div: Sum does not converge.Sum::div: Sum does not converge.{Sum[E^x, {x, 1, [Infinity]}, Regularization -> None], 
>    Sum[E^x, {x, 1, [Infinity]}, Regularization -> "Cesaro"], 
>    Sum[E^x, {x, 1, [Infinity]}, Regularization -> "Abel"], 
>    Sum[E^x, {x, 1, [Infinity]}, Regularization -> "Euler"], -(
>     E/(-1 + E)), 
>    Sum[E^x, {x, 1, [Infinity]}, Regularization -> "Dirichlet"]}